# Questions regarding customer interaction allowed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Would questions regarding how to deal with customers be acceptable? The FAQ is sort of vague in this regard...

Comment: My gut response is no, because to me that firmly sits in the "How do I perform the job of a ..." category of questions, but I think it depends on what you mean by "customers" (e.g. if you mean clients, then client relations stuff might be, while general customer service might not).  Can you provide more context?

Comment: Closely related discussion here: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/102/42 seems to imply we're against it

Answer (score 4):

This is not an official answer, by any means.

My opinion is that it is like anything else that can have *in-context* and *out-of-context* relationships to the workplace.

Certainly your relationship and interactions with your boss are on topic.  However, there are absolutely components of your relationship with your boss that are very job-specific; and those would [probably be off topic](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/102/42).

I think the same would go for customer relationships.  How you might acquire them, when your role in the sales/service process dictates that you should or shouldn't contact them — these things would be off topic.

But, just as we have many workplace relationship questions here, there are certain aspects of "how to deal with customers" that would definitely be on topic.  Here are some samples that might be:

- A customer asked me to go around my boss and approve an invoice.  This customer is very important to the company.  How should I deal with this?
- I need to contact a customer from a company I no longer work for.  How can I do this appropriately?

I believe questions like this are every bit as on-topic as other workplace relationship questions we already support, so in answer to "would questions regarding how to deal with customers be acceptable?" I don't think there is one answer that fits all questions.

Comment: I agree with this; I hope the OP edits his question to provide more context to the situation he wants to ask about, so that we can discuss it & provide more concrete guidance.